# cut function : Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the content in a column in my Dataframe to "good" or 'bad.'
The column is filled with numbers from 1 to 10.
1-5 is bad and 6-10 is good.
For this, I want to use the cut method.

```
bins = (1, 5.5, 10)
rating = ['bad', 'good']
game['useropinion'] = pd.cut(rating, bins)
```

the result after run:

```
Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
game['useropinion'] = pd.cut(game['useropinion'], bins, labels=rating)
```

EDIT:
And to answer what is wrong, you are trying to cut rating instead of the useropinion data so naturaly you get a TypeError, since rating is an array of strings and your bins are numeric.
'<U32' means little endian unicode 32 and your bins are of type float 64.
I hope that answers your question.

Comment: So, this was caused by a typo?

Comment: It was caused by using the function in an unintended way.